# Verifying Newton's Binomial Series for $(1+x)^{−2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

> Verify the consistency of Newton’s Binomial series for the function
>   $(1+x)^{−2}$ in two ways:
>
> $(a)$ by multiplying the usual geometric series for $(1 +x)^{−1}$with
>   itself
>
> $(b)$ by differentiation of the series for $(1 +x)^{−1}$

$(a)$ I have that Newton's Binomial series says that

$$(1+x)^p=1+px+\frac{p(p−1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{p(p−1)(p−2)}{3!}x^3+···$$

I have that the geometric series for $(1 +x)^{−1}$ is given by

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1+x}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-x)^k\\\\
&=-x^0+(-x)^1+(-x)^2+(-x)^3+...\\\\
&=1-x+x^2-x^3+...
\end{align*}$$

Thus

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)^2
&=(1-x+x^2-x^3+...)(1-x+x^2-x^3+...)\\\\
&=(1-x+x^2-x^3+...)\\\\
& +(-x+x^2-x^3+...)\\\\
& +(x^2-x^3+...)\\\\
& +(-x^3+...)\\\\
&=1-2x+3x^2-4x^3+...
\end{align*}$$

Checking that this equals Newton's Binomial series

$$(1+x)^p=1+px+\frac{p(p−1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{p(p−1)(p−2)}{3!}x^3+···$$

where $p=-2$

$$\begin{align*}
(1+x)^{-2}
&=1-2x+\frac{-2(-3)}{2!}x^2+\frac{-2(-3)(-4)}{3!}x^3+···\\\\
&=1-2x+3x^2-4x^3+... \checkmark
\end{align*}$$

Is this a valid proof?

$(b)$

I have that $$\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t}=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}$$

but I'm not sure how to use this fact.

Comment: For the second... you integrated when you were supposed to differentiate. For the first, it is not yet enough - you've only checked four of the infinitely many terms! Also, you wrote = when you certainly didn't mean it.

Comment: I wasn't sure how else to do it without implying that the pattern continues.

Comment: And I know I'm supposed to differentiate but that's a given formula that I think I could make use of. I was thinking maybe to integrate the RHS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, first idea is right. More formally,
$$
\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i x^i \right)
\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j x^j \right)
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i x^i (-1)^{n-i}x^{n-i}
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^n x^n
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) (-1)^n x^n.
$$
On the second one, note that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} (1+x)^{-1} = -(1+x)^{-2},
$$
thus
$$
(1+x)^{-2}
 = -\frac{d}{dx} (1+x)^{-1}
 = -\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i x^i
 = -\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i \frac{d}{dx} x^i
 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^{i-1}ix^{i-1}
 = \sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i (i+1)x^i
$$

Comment: Thanks! Not having to expand everything out makes things a lot nicer!

Comment: @Remy yes, the formalisms of manipulating sums directly serve a good help here

Answer (score 1):

The binomial expansion is
$$
\left( {1 + x} \right)^{\, - 2}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( \matrix{
   - 2 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \matrix{
  k + 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)x^{\,k} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( {k + 1} \right)x^{\,k} } 
$$
where "upper negation" of the binomial has been used

The multiplication of geometric series gives
$$
\eqalign{
  & {1 \over {1 + x}}{1 \over {1 + x}} = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} x^{\,k} } \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} x^{\,j} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k + j} x^{\,k + j} } } \quad \left| \matrix{
  \;0 \le k + j = s \hfill \cr 
  \;0 \le j = s - k\; \Rightarrow \;0 \le k \le s \hfill \cr}  \right.\;\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,s} {\left( {\sum\limits_{0 \le k \le s} 1 } \right)\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,s} x^{\,s} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,s} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,s} \left( {s + 1} \right)x^{\,s} }  \cr} 
$$

and differentiating the geometric series
$$
\eqalign{
  & {d \over {dx}}\left( {1 + x} \right)^{\, - 1}  =  - \left( {1 + x} \right)^{\, - 2}  = {d \over {dx}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} x^{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} k\,x^{\,k - 1} }  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} k\,x^{\,k - 1} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k + 1} \left( {k + 1} \right)\,x^{\,k} }  =  - \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( {k + 1} \right)x^{\,k} }  \cr} 
$$